# Git checkout from one directory to another on server (cloudways)

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, cloudways

I have a `laravel` app on Cloudway DigitalOcean, my app in `/public_html` , I want to update my app using `git` , so I have created folder `private_html/git` , where I pull my edited project from `bitbucket`, now I want to checkout it to my `public_html/` , how do I do that ? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can either deploy the changes to `public/html` via git or manually copy the files across.

**Manually copy option**

Depending on full path, something like:

`cp -a private_html/git/. public_html/`

Note: -a is a recursive option that preserves file attributes

This won't remove any files that have been removed in `private_html/git` so you would have to do that manually, or remove everything before copying the files across.

**Git pull option**

First, make sure you have pushed all the changes made in `private_html/git` to your remote (bitbucket repo).

Set up the current copy in `public_html/` as a git repo.

In public_html/

`git init`

Then add the bit bucket remote

`git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:user-name/repo-name`

Note: Get the proper bitbucket remote from your bitbucket account

Then pull the changes from the remote

`git fetch --all`

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Warning: You'll lose any differences that are currently in `public/html` so be careful. Always a good idea to back up everything before these kinds of changes so I'd suggesting archiving the code in `public_html` before overwriting it.

Comment: I think you're missing some steps on git pull because there's already a repository in that work tree.